# What are the best ways to tutor artifacts in mono red

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I've recently built a [Jaya Ballard, Task Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jaya%20Ballard%2C%20Task%20Mage) EDH deck, based around stacking Jaya with equipments get the most advantage out of her burn effects.

I'm having a hard time finding cards that let me find the artifact equipments I need to really optimize her. Are there any good cards, either colorless or mono-red that let me find those cards?

Comment: How does Jaya Ballard synergize with equipment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tutor options in red are limited and/or risky by design, or require certain other resources as payment that aren't necessarily easy to come by, but here are a few staples and other options that might be interesting for you:

Red

- [Gamble](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gamble)
- [Fervent Mastery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fervent%20Mastery)
- [Godo, Bandit Warlord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Godo%2C%20Bandit%20Warlord)
- [Hoarding Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hoarding%20Dragon)
- [Magda, Brazen Outlaw](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Magda%2C%20Brazen%20Outlaw)

Colorless

- [Inventors' Fair](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Inventors%27%20Fair)
- [Kuldotha Forgemaster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kuldotha%20Forgemaster)
- [Mangara's Tome](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mangara%27s%20Tome)
- [Planar Portal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Planar%20Portal)
- [Ring of Three Wishes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ring%20of%20Three%20Wishes)
- [Skyship Weatherlight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skyship%20Weatherlight)
- [Tamiyo's Journal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tamiyo%27s%20Journal)
- [Urza's Saga](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urza%27s%20Saga)

There's also another card that isn't technically speaking a tutor, since you don't put the card into your hand, but into your graveyard, but in the right deck, this one works really well:

- [Goblin Engineer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Engineer)

Comment: In fact, the options are so limited that to get a reasonably long list, even when I tried to only include the cards on the playable side, I had to include some rather mediocre ones...

Comment: What about Godo, Bandit Warlord?